# "Extent" variables in WMS Layer

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

I am pretty new in this topic and tried some codes and layers from [ArcGIS site here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) and still don't understand meaning of `extent: new Extent (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, spatial Reference)`. These are supposed to be coordinates for a square the layer will be working in, isn't it? If so, why there 2 types of them (Initial and Full) given, ex: [US Rivers and Cities example here](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer)  and when I tried some other values, showing even another country it worked?

Answer (score 1):

The link you give in your example doesn't point directly to any WMS metadata;  you need to click the WMS link in the page for the WMS metadata.

An OGC WMS in fact doesn't have an *extent* parameter.  If we look at your US Rivers and Cities example, the [WMS GetCapabilities request](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS) response, you can see that each layer has a Geographic Bounding Box, like:

```
 <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
  <westBoundLongitude>-164.765831</westBoundLongitude>
  <eastBoundLongitude>-67.790980</eastBoundLongitude>
  <southBoundLatitude>25.845557</southBoundLatitude>
  <northBoundLatitude>70.409756</northBoundLatitude>
 </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
```

Which is a **hint** of the extent of the layer.

There is also the coordinate reference systems supported by the layer, such as:

```
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
```

and the extent of the layer expressed in terms of those coordinate reference systems as BoundingBox, such as:

```
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-164.765831" miny="25.845557" maxx="-67.790980" maxy="70.409756"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="25.845557" miny="-164.765831" maxx="70.409756" maxy="-67.790980"/>
```